# StringBuffer setLength vs substring

Tags: java, string, substring, stringbuilder

To trim to a length in stringbuilder.

What should I use?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("203253/62331066                          ");
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("203253/62331066                          ");
int newLen = Math.min(sb.length(), ACCT_LENGTH);
sb = new StringBuilder(sb.substring(0, newLen));
sb1.setLength(newLen);
System.out.println(sb);
System.out.println(sb1);
```

`setLength(newLength)` or `new StringBuilder` with `substring()`?

Comment: Do you just need the String that would result from a `toString()` call, or do you need to keep using the StringBuilder?

Comment: I removed toString(), but, not sure why the question was downvoted. Isn't it a valid question?

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setLength` is more efficient as it simply changes an internal counter that tracks the size of the StringBuilder without changing anything else (assuming the new length is smaller of course).

`substring` creates a new String which implies an array copy.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new StringBuilder kind of defeats the purpose of using a StringBuilder, rather than just a String... namely buffering instead of creating a new object. So I would vote for setLength().

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you intend to do.

If you're done with your `StringBuilder` and won't re-use the part of it that you intend to trim, then I can't think of a good reason not to use `setLength`: it has no memory cost, as opposed to `substring` which creates a new instance and clones the internal character array.

If, on the other hand, you intend to keep using the content of the initial `StringBuilder` but need another instance to store the substring, then `substring` is the better choice.

In concrete terms, in the code you pasted, are you going to keep using `sb` or discard it and work with `sb1` only? if the former, use `substring`, if the later, `setLength`.